# Разделение бизнес логики от БД или почему нельзя работать с Entity (java)

Tags: java, jpa, entity, dto

Вопрос по JPA и подходам в проектировании сервисов.
В проектах где я участвовал просили (даже требовали) после получения Entity из репозитория необходимо сделать сервис (Назовем его RepositoryService), который будет ее преобразовывать в DTO и затем передавать в другие сервисы. И наоборот передавать в RepositoryService только DTO который будет ее преобразовывать в Entity и сохранять через JPA. Внятно объяснить для чего это нужно не смогли. Гугл тоже не очень помог.

Таков путь:

```
JPA.findAll() -> RepositoryService.entitiyToDto() -> ...обработка другими сервисами... -> RepositoryService.DtoToEntity() -> JPA.saveAll()
```

Вопрос для чего это нужно и какие могут реальные риски? Насколько я понимаю, когда я получил Entity и отдал ее другим сервисам транзакция уже закрылась и сущность перешла в состояние Detached, то есть это по сути можно использовать ее как DTO. А издержки на преобразования DtoToEntity могут быть немаленькими.

Comment: это в значительной мере философская тема. Но: а что, если у вашей сущности есть lazy-поля, которые вы не инициализировали в транзакции? А что, если структура в БД (и, соответственно, сущности) поменялась? Переписывать всё, куда эта сущность отдавалась? А что, если есть сразу и первый и второй вопросы? Вот тут https://youtu.be/gD8xUkZW1GU?si=8gm2CXIiVTaQTa4v в качестве одной из тем поднимается данный вопрос.

Comment: Если не смогли внятно обьяснить, то зачем тогда попросили? Вероятно такой подход сейчас в моде, но никто внятно не может объяснить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На самом деле здесь не все так очевидно, как обычно рассказывают.

Во-первых, системы с JPA, где не используется DTO действительно существуют (правда, не ясно насколько хорошо они живут), более того, существуют фреймворки, где DTO не используется, в пример можно привести [Jmix framework](https://jpa-buddy.com/blog/entity-to-dto-how-to/) и в целом здесь возникает две идеи:

- у системы есть внешние (не контролируемые разработчиком) контракты на передаваемые данные - здесь нужно использовать DTO, без вариантов
- внешних контрактов нет, но у условного архитектора есть мысли, что когда-то в будущем может случиться так, что система переедет на другое персистентное хранилище, и тут-то все увидят всю крутость проектирования архитектуры - нет,  так может получиться только в том случае, если фишки JPA не используются, совсем, т.е. если мы делаем ИС исходя из предположения, что рано или поздно мы выкинем JPA, то это значит, что всякие `@ManyToOne` и `@OneToMany` мы использовать не должны

Во-вторых, на самом деле проблемы не использования DTO возникают гораздо раньше, давайте, к примеру, рассмотрим два метода:

```java
void processOrder(OrderDTO order) {

}
```

и

```java
void processOrder(OrderEntity order) {

}
```

в чем существенное различие этих методов?

- в первом случае, мы знаем, что данные прилетели от клиента, и нет никаких оснований считать их доверенными, т.е. мы должны внедрить или в метод или в вызывающую сторону некие проверки
- во втором случае, если у нас есть разделение на `Entity` и `DTO`, то никакие проверки нам внедрять не нужно - считаем, что они были сделаны ранее, а если разделения нет, то увы, нам придется постоянно следить за кодом (условно перенос метода из одного сервиса в другой может сломать безопасность).

т.е. появление `DTO` сразу же проводит границу между доверенными данными и мусором из вне.

Comment: Спасибо! Покопавшись немного с кодом обнаружил еще один большой плюс ДТО. Если у нас есть различные репозитории(таблицы) с похожим набором данных мы можем смапить в одно и то же ДТО. Даже если их нет они вполне могут появиться в будущем. И можно работать с ними одинаково, то есть принцип абстракции раскрывается во всех красе.